# Sql query help to count no of rows

Tags: sql-server

I wonder any of you would help me. I have a `class` table

and my question is how to count how many students are enrolled in classes that are currently running (count each student just once, even if he or she is enrolled in many classes).

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you know that the class is currently running?

Comment: I have another table which has the start date and end date. All the classes in the class table is currently running

Comment: then you should post that data and the table structure for all tables that will be needed to return the result.

Comment: This is the course details table

ClassID Subject Level StartDate FinishDate Cost                  C001 Fiddle Advanced 2012-10-04 2012-12-17 £60.00                 C002 Gaelic Intermediate 2012-09-27 2012-11-26 £50.00             C003 CeilidhDance Beginners 2012-11-10 2013-01-14 £30.00          C004 Tin Whistle Beginners 2012-10-04 2012-12-10 £45.00

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT StudentName)`:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT StudentName)
 FROM TableName
 -- You can add a condition here to get only the classes that currently running
 -- like WHERE Date BETWEEN ....
```

**Update:** You can join the other table to get only the courses that are currently running:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.stuid)
FROM @Courses c
INNER JOIN @courseDetails cd 
        ON c.ClassID = cd.ClassID 
       AND c.EndrolledDate BETWEEN cd.StartDate AND cd.FinishDate
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f7ff/1)

Comment: this is just returning the count of student Ids

Comment: Do I need a subquery for this

Comment: @Aberdeen - Yes you can use subquery, but why not `JOIN`?

Comment: 'SELECT c.ClassID, COUNT(DISTINCT c.studentid)
FROM Class c
INNER JOIN CourseDetails cd 
        ON c.ClassID = cd.ClassID 
       AND c.EnrolDate BETWEEN cd.StartDate AND cd.EndDate
    group by c.ClassID' It returns C001 2 which is right and Coo2 1 this is wrong

Comment: @Aberdeen - Why `coo2` is wrong? could you explain what is the desired output for this? and please see the sql fiddle demo above and you can try it and explain how it should work..

Comment: The output should be C001 - 2 C002 - 0 (as S001 entrolled in many classes he is countes ad 1 in C001) C003 - 1 and C004 - 0 (as s001 entrolled in many classes)

Comment: I want to count how many students are enrolled in classes that are currently running (count each student just once, even if he or she is enrolled in many classes).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

That will count the number of distinct values in the column having name COLUMN_NAME in the table TABLE_NAME.

Hope this answer was helpful.

Comment: This returns the count of students as three I need to show count of students for each class and student should be once)

Comment: You want to display the counts for all the classes individually using one statement?

Comment: yeas I want to count Count each student 
just once, even if he or she is enrolled in many classes